# Search AD users for a user

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have a query regarding searching AD.
I have written this  piece of code for moving HomeDrives of users which does not have an AD account in the AD.

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\server1\path" -Force |
    Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name = Split-Path -Path $_ -Leaf

        $ADResult = ([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$Name)").Findone()

        if (!($ADResult)) {
            $sNewPath = "\\server1\newpath"
            Move-Item -Path $_.Fullname -Destination $sNewPath -Force
        }
    }
```

The thing is that I want to run this from another server and the AD is on another server.But this:

```
$ADResult = ([adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$Name)").Findone()
```

will run only if AD is on this server.

So I want to replace this line with a solution that can access AD which is on server2.

Can I use `Get-ADUser` or `Search-ADAccount` to achieve this?

Comment: "But this ... will run only if AD is on this server" - have you tried it? An AD query works from domain member computers.

Comment: tried it, can u suggest something?

Comment: What happened when you tried? (What specifically did you try?) Remember: We can't see your screen. Update your question with the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: As @Bill_Stewart said: using an ADSI searcher should work from any domain member. Using AD cmdlets is also a possibility, but requires installing the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) first. How to install them depends on which operating system you want to install them on.

Comment: To use Get-Aduser or Search-ADAccount - would require installation of RSAT? its win sv 2008 R2

Comment: On Server 2008 R2 you can enable the AD management tools in the Features section of Server Manager.

Comment: Again: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

I use:
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount

You can specify the username with a filter.
Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -filter 'name="username"'

Comment: If you have anything more than a single small domain, this approach can be unusably slow.